# How are loops represented in an edge set?

Tags: graph-theory

When a node $v_1$ in a graph has an edge to itself (a loop), will this be represented as $\{v_1\}$ or as $\{v_1, v_1\}$?

Comment: If the graph is $G = (V, E)$, and if $E \subseteq V \times V$ then we have $(v_1, v_1) \in E$.

Comment: You write $E\subseteq V\times V$ if you're talking about **digraphs**. I believe the OP is talking about  an **undirected** graph. In that case it's usual to consider $E\subseteq\binom V2$ for loopless graphs, or $E\subseteq\binom V2\cup\binom V1$ for a simple undirected graph with loops (a "pseudograph").

Answer (score 0):

Loops are represented within the edge set as:

### $$\{v_1,v_1\}\in\large\bf\epsilon$$

$\{v_1\}$ would be meaningless as a vertex cannot be an edge, as an edge requires $2$ vertices.

Comment: But $\{v_1,v_1\}=\{v_1\}$. An ordinary edge requires two vertices, but a loop requires only one vertex. Of course the loop is not the vertex.

Comment: That is the way I have usually seen it being represented however I was reading a discrete math textbook and I saw loops being represented with a single element, so I just wanted to be sure.